# Didn't get my desired output while use this cubic-bezier(0.52,-1.59, 0.85, 3.63) function in my css code

Tags: html, css

My code snippet is given below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .box{
            width:100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin:0 auto;
            background-color:red;
            margin-top:5%;
            transition-property: all;
            transition-duration:10s;
            transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.52,-1.59, 0.85, 3.63);
        }
        .box:hover{
            width:500px;
            height:500px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the code snippet I have used this "cubic-bezier(0.52,-1.59, 0.85, 3.63)" function. And this function gave me the following curve:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHgWr.png)
what i am asuming as my output from the curve is - Firstly,at the beginning it will decrease box(div class name) width and then at the close to the end,it will increase the size beyond its actual size.But as a result i found something different then my assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the hovering.

If you run this snippet, which is the same as in the question but with a 100s rather than a 10s duration you will see that initially the square shrinks, as desired, but it gets to the point (depending on where the cursor is in relation to the square) that the cursor ends up outside the square.

This means it is no longer hovering so the square returns to its initial size, at which point the cursor is hovering again so the transition is repeated. Hence the sort of pulsing effect.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .box{
            width:100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin:0 auto;
            background-color:red;
            margin-top:5%;
            transition-property: all;
            transition-duration:100s;
            transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.52,-1.59, 0.85, 3.63);
        }
        .box:hover{
            width:500px;
            height:500px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

One way to get round this would be to keep the actual square constant size, so the hover doesn't leave it, and put the transform onto an after pseudo element that has the red color while the square itself is transparent. That way the hovering cursor remains within the square and you don't get the pulsing effect.

Here's an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .box{
            width:100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin:0 auto;
            background-color:transparent;
            margin-top:5%;
            position: absolute;
        }
        
        .box::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            transition-property: all;
            transition-duration:10s;
            transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.52,-1.59, 0.85, 3.63);
        }
        .box:hover::after{
            width:500%;
            height:500%;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```